# overlay div overrides another in Openlayers 3.9.0

Tags: openlayers

I have years to play with Openlayers and I am new to Openlayers 3.

I have the following code

```
<div id="overlay" style="background-color: white; border-radius:10px; border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px 10px;"> 
<div id="overlay2" style="background-color: yellow; width: 20px; height: 20px; border-radius: 10px;">

var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
    });

var center = ol.proj.transform([-1.812, 52.443], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');

var overlay = new ol.Overlay({
    element: document.getElementById('overlay'),
    positioning: 'bottom-center'
});


var overlay2 = new ol.Overlay({
    position: center,
    element: document.getElementById('overlay2')
});

var view = new ol.View({
    center: center,
    zoom: 6
});


var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [layer],
    overlays: [overlay2],
    view: view
});


map.on('click', function(event) {
    var coord = event.coordinate;
    var degrees = ol.proj.transform(coord, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326')
    var hdms = ol.coordinate.toStringHDMS(degrees);
    var element = overlay.getElement();
    element.innerHTML = hdms;
    overlay.setPosition(coord);
    map.addOverlay(overlay);
});
```

`overlay2` should just stay on the top of the map and do nothing.

`overlay` creates an info box over the map, where you clicked, showing info about degrees etc.

`overlay` works, but I cannot see `overlay2` and I cannot understand why. Console gives no errors and when I hit `ol.Overlay.length` , says `1`.

Does it get overridden?

And why?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't close your div tags

see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rgdwz814/1/)